# How to properly access children by filtering parents in a single REST API call

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm rewriting an API to be more RESTful, but I'm struggling with a design issue. I'll explain the situation first and then my question.

SITUATION:

I have two sets resources `users` and `items`. Each `user` has a list of `item`, so the resource path would like something like this:

`api/v1/users/{userId}/items`

Also each `user` has an `isPrimary` property, but only one user can be primary at a time. This means that if I want to get the primary user you'd do something like this:

`api/v1/users?isPrimary=true`

This should return a single "primary" user.

I have client of my API that wants to get the items of the primary user, but can't make two API calls (one to get the primary user and the second to get the items of the user, using the userId). Instead the client would like to make a single API call.

QUESTION:

How should I got about designing an API that fetches the `items` of a single user in only one API call when all the client has is the `isPrimary` query parameter for the `user`?

MY THOUGHTS:

I think I have a some options:

Option 1) `api/v1/users?isPrimary=true` will return the list of items along with the user data.

I don't like this one, because I have other API clients that call `api/v1/users` or `api/v1/users?isPrimary=true` to only get and parse through user data NOT item data. A user can have thousands of items, so returning those items every time would be taxing on both the client and the service.

Option 2) `api/v1/users/items?isPrimary=true`

I also don't like this because it's ugly and not really RESTful since there is not `{userId}` in the path and `isPrimary` isn't a property of `items`.

Option 3) `api/v1/users?isPrimary=true&isShowingItems=true`

This is like the first one, but I use another query parameter to flag whether or not to show the items belonging to the user in the response. The problem is that the query parameter is misleading because there is no `isShowingItems` property associated with a `user`.

Any help that you all could provide will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just commenting since this is largely subjective.  Given your constraints, I don't see the problem with you adding a query param for including the items belonging to the user.  The root object returned by api/v1/users would still be a "User", and now you'll simply be giving your callers a way to include items belonging to that user.  If anything, I'd propose a rename of your query param to "includeItems".  Seems to more natural that way.

Comment: Thanks @Tung I think you and Evert had similar ideas and I'm going to go that route with a flag in my JSON which can be used as a query param to either include or not include items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real standard solution for this, and all of your solutions are in my mind valid. So my answer will be a bit subjective.

Have you looked at [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) for your API format? HAL has a standard way to embed data from one resources into another (using `_embedded`) and it sounds like a pretty valid use-case for this.

The server can decide whether to embed the items based on a number of criteria, but one cheap solution might be to just add a query parameter like `?embed=items`

Even if you don't use HAL, conceptually you could still copy this behavior similarly. Or maybe you only use `_embedded`. At least it's re-using an existing idea over building something new.

Aside from that practical solution, there is nothing in un-RESTful about exposing data at multiple endpoints. So if you created a resource like:

```
/v1/primary-user-with-items
```

Then this might be ugly and inconsistent with the rest of your API, but not inherently
'not RESTful' (sorry for the double negative).

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. The API is using the [google api style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml) for formatting it's responses and request JSON which is sort of similar to HAL. You brought up a great idea, so I'm going to add a flag inside my JSON to filter whether or not to return the "embedded" items or not. I think that'll do the job. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Actually, I'm going to change that slightly by allowing for "partial" GETs like the one illustrated [here](http://yaoganglian.com/2013/07/01/partial-response/). I still think it falls in line with what you suggested and allows me to follow the Google JSON style guide.

Answer (score 0):

You could include a List<User.Fieldset> parameter called fieldsets, and then include things if they are specified in fieldsets. This has the benefit that you can reuse the pattern by adding fieldsets onto any object in your API that has fields you might wish to include.

> `api/v1/users?isPrimary=true&fieldsets=items`